# Who's responsible for Authentication in multi-client MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

my situation is the following:

- I have a REST API Node.js server using MongoDB, which will serve data to the clients.
- I have one web client which will fetch data from the API service and provide social authentication.

For the purposes of my question, let's assume that I have two different clients - both web apps. In this situation, who should be responsible for social authentication, sessions, cookies, etc? The user database should be shared between all clients, but I feel like authentication and API should be two separate services.

What is the most common approach in this situation?

Client will be built with AngularJS, REST API service is built with Node.js, Express, MongoDB, Mongoose and eventually Passport.js when I figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you feel like authentication and API should be separated?

Answer (score 1):

> but I feel like authentication and API should be two separate services.

If you have to ask, you don't want 2 separate services. (services meaning independent network daemons/express apps)

Start with just 2 separate modules within your single express app. You can have an `auth.js` module that uses passport to handle authentication and session issues and then one module file for each entity in your API. If you need more than 1000 lines of code in your auth.js file considering passport is doing most of the hard work for you, something is going wrong. Take a step back and ask for a code review.

If you want each of your 2 web apps to have it's own Express server, just factor the `auth.js` module out into its own shareable npm module and require it from each web app.

Splitting things out into microservices is for large team projects at scale. Stick with a single simple express server for the first several years (or forever for projects that don't support a rapid-growth startup).

Comment: "for each entity in your API" - by entity do you mean endpoint?

Comment: Otherwise I agree and I think I will follow your advise. Separate module for auth, instead of separate service.

Comment: Yes, I generally separate my REST APIs into modules for each entity which usually also maps to one endpoint (but sometimes several). So if I was building a car dealership there would be a module for vehicles, dealers, sales, etc.